# dotnet-counters thinks dotnet needs to be installed even though it already is and DOTNET_ROOT is set

Tags: .net, bash, ubuntu, dotnet-counters

I've got dotnet installed in /root/.dotnet and dotnet-counters installed in /root/.dotnet/tools. I use create 2 symlinks to make the runnable from anywhere.

```
ln -s /root/.dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
ln -s /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-counters /usr/local/bin
```

I set DOTNET_ROOT manually and can confirm that it's been set properly

```
echo $DOTNET_ROOT    
/root/.dotnet
```

However, if I try to execute dotnet-counters, I get this

```
sudo dotnet-counters --version
You must install .NET to run this Application.
...
.NET location: Not Found
```

Why can't dotnet-counters find dotnet?

Results of sudo dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   6.0.413
Commit:    10710f7d8e

 

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     ubuntu
OS Version:  20.04
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
Base Path:   /root/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.413/

 

global.json file:
  Not found

 

Host:
  Version:      6.0.21
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       e40b3abf1b

 

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.413 [/root/.dotnet/sdk]

 

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.21 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

 

Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

 

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info

.NET (and .NET Core) - introduction and overview

Learn about .NET (and .NET Core). .NET is a free, open-source development platform for building many kinds of apps.
```

Comment: What is the `dotnet --info` output ?

Comment: @JRichardsz Added sudo dotnet --info output to top post, couldn't format it in comments

Answer (score 0):

I tried on a fresh ubuntu machine and after installation (`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters`) I got this error

```
foo@bar:/# dotnet-counters --version
bash: dotnet-counters: command not found
foo@bar:/#
```

Not equal to you error but I fixed adding **/root/.dotnet/tools** to the PATH

```
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

After that, `dotnet-counters --version` returned a success response

```
foo@bar:/# dotnet-counters --version
7.0.430602+c9c987585e1fa9a8a8a5e1ffb60a70f85b0da4ca
```

### Tips

- Check where is dotnet-counters using `whereis dotnet-counters`
- dotnet-counter installation don't need manually symlinks. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters#install
- Use docker to reproduce and fix the issue: `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 bash`
- Make the PATH changes persistent (upon restart) adding the follwing lines to your **~/.bash_profile**

```
# Add .NET Core SDK tools
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```